# Unable to locate appender

Tags: log4j, log4j2

We are moving from log4j1.x to log4j2

Changed the properties file to xml file to support log4j2

Below is the xml file which we are using

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Configuration status="debug">
     <Appenders>
       <RollingFile name="syslog" fileName="/var/log/stor/gui/gui.log" filePattern="/var/log/stor/gui/gui-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log" append="true">
         <PatternLayout>
           <pattern>%d %p %m%n</pattern>
         </PatternLayout>
       <Filters>
       <!-- Now deny warn, error and fatal messages -->
        <ThresholdFilter level="warn"  onMatch="DENY"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
        <ThresholdFilter level="error" onMatch="DENY"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
        <ThresholdFilter level="fatal" onMatch="DENY"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
       <!-- This filter accepts info, warn, error, fatal and denies debug/trace -->
       <ThresholdFilter level="info"  onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
       </Filters>
       <Policies>
        <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="16 MB"/>
       </Policies>
       <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="1"/>
     </RollingFile>
   </Appenders>
  <appenders>
    <RollingFile name="requestUrilog" fileName="/var/log/stor/gui/requestUrilog.log" filePattern="/var/log/stor/gui/requestUrilog-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log" append="true">
      <PatternLayout>
      <pattern>%d %p %m%n</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Filters>
      <!-- Now deny warn, error and fatal messages -->
    <ThresholdFilter level="warn"  onMatch="DENY"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
    <ThresholdFilter level="error" onMatch="DENY"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
    <ThresholdFilter level="fatal" onMatch="DENY"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
    <!-- This filter accepts info, warn, error, fatal and denies debug/trace -->
    <ThresholdFilter level="info"  onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
    </Filters>
    <Policies>
     <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
     <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
     <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="8 MB"/>
    </Policies>
   <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="4"/>
  </RollingFile>
</appenders>
<appenders>
<RollingFile name="userlog" fileName="/var/log/stor/gui/userlog.log" filePattern="/var/log/stor/gui/userlog-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log" append="true">
  <PatternLayout>
    <pattern>%d %p %m%n</pattern>
  </PatternLayout>
  <Filters>
 <!-- Now deny warn, error and fatal messages -->
    <ThresholdFilter level="warn"  onMatch="DENY"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
    <ThresholdFilter level="error" onMatch="DENY"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
    <ThresholdFilter level="fatal" onMatch="DENY"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
    <!-- This filter accepts info, warn, error, fatal and denies debug/trace -->
    <ThresholdFilter level="info"  onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
  </Filters>
  <Policies>
    <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="8 MB"/>
  </Policies>
  <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="4"/>
</RollingFile>
</appenders>
<Loggers>
<Logger name="com.tms.gui.sys" additivity="false" level="info">
  <AppenderRef ref="syslog"/>
</Logger>
<Logger name="com.tms.gui.requestUri" additivity="false" level="info">
  <AppenderRef ref="requestUrilog"/>
</Logger>
<Logger name="com.tms.gui.user" additivity="false" level="info">
  <AppenderRef ref="userlog"/>
</Logger>
<Root level="info">
  <AppenderRef ref="syslog"/>
</Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

below is the debuf info which we are getting for the error

```
  DEBUG Found factory method [createLoggers]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Loggers org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin.createLoggers(org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig[]).
   2016-01-14 12:40:14,757 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Calling createLoggers on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin for element Loggers with params(={com.tms.gui.sys, com.tms.gui.requestUri, com.tms.gui.user, root})
   2016-01-14 12:40:14,758 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Built Plugin[name=loggers] OK from factory method.
   2016-01-14 12:40:14,758 localhost-startStop-1 ERROR Unable to locate appender requestUrilog for logger com.tms.gui.requestUri
   2016-01-14 12:40:14,758 localhost-startStop-1 ERROR Unable to locate appender syslog for logger
   2016-01-14 12:40:14,758 localhost-startStop-1 ERROR Unable to locate appender syslog for logger com.tms`enter code here`.gui.sys
   2016-01-14 12:40:14,759 localhost-startStop-1 DEBUG Configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/opt/stor/gui/www/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml] initialized
```

please guide us on what we are doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

The ThresholdFilter checks for the level of the log event being the same or more specific than the specified level. So the filter that checks for level "warn" and on a match does a DENY will also deny error and fatal as well, making the next two filters unnecessary.

Can you provide the debug info for creating the appenders? It is possible that the appenders can't be found because problems were encountered creating them, possibly because of permissions problems creating a file in the /var/log directory.